# Match word index

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have to know in which word the match occurred.

I thought is possible to use below code, but is give me the index and doesn't have a word counter inside.

Is it possible to get back information after which word the match occured?

```
const string stringToTest = "Am Rusch";
const string patternToMatch = @"\bRusch*";

Regex regex = new Regex(patternToMatch, RegexOptions.Compiled);

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(stringToTest);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Index);
}
```

The word count shall be 1, because match was found in second word.

Comment: What is the problem to use regex on each word?

Comment: What is a word? `how.many,words are(in)this|sentence?8`

Comment: No. The regex knows nothing about previous words, because they didn't match the expression. If you need to know which word, why can't you just avoid the regex altogether and use `String.Split` and then iterate through the array?

Comment: In normal code I use regex pattern because I have to find different alternatives too and therefore regex is really good. I combine both Regex and String Split. Thank you the split I had not in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Split the `string stringToTest` by spaces, then you can easily find out in which word the match occured

Comment: This is the same as you say to use .NET for his task. Please, be more specific in answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can play a little trick to get word index which is after getting index of desired string, run another regex to get its word index.

```
const string stringToTest = "Am Rusch, you dare";
const string patternToMatch = @"\bRusch*";

Regex regex = new Regex(patternToMatch, RegexOptions.Compiled);

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(stringToTest);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var wordIndex = Regex.Split(stringToTest.Substring(0, match.Index), "\\W").Count()-1;
    Console.WriteLine("Word Index: " + wordIndex);
}
```

This will return string `Word Index: 1`

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a pattern matching tool which is not designed to **interpret** the text.

If one wants a basic word count use the regex index found and pass it to a method which has the heuristics of *what is a word*; such as this extension:

```
public static int AtWord(this string strBuffer, int index)
{ 
    int foundAt = -1;

    var splits = Regex.Split(strBuffer.Substring(0, index), @"(\s+)");

    if (splits.Any())
       foundAt = splits.Count() - 2;

    return foundAt;
}
```

Used as

```
const string stringToTest = "Am Rusch Lunch";
const string patternToMatch = @"Rusch";

var match = Regex.Match(stringToTest, patternToMatch);

var wordIndex = stringToTest.AtWord(match.Index); // Returns 1, for a zero based list
```

Comment: I used string.split, but your solution looks more professional and is better readable.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest method is to split the string into words and find the index of the word that matches the pattern:

```
const string stringToTest = "Am Rusch";
const string patternToMatch = @"\bRusch*";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Split(stringToTest,@"[^\w\p{M}]+")
        .Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m))
        .ToList()
        .FindIndex(p => Regex.IsMatch(p,patternToMatch))
);
// Output: 1
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/X3Zibw)

*Explanations*:

- `Regex.Split(stringToTest,@"[^\w\p{M}]+")` splits the string into words as `[^\w\p{M}]+` matches one or more symbols other than word and diacritics symbols
- `.Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m))` removes all empty elements
- `.FindIndex(p => Regex.IsMatch(p,patternToMatch))` fetches the index of the word you need.

A [*matching* alternative](http://ideone.com/e85FYB) in order not remove empty elements:

```
Regex.Matches(stringToTest,@"[\w\p{M}]+") // Match all words
        .Cast<Match>()                    // Cast to Matches array
        .Select(m => m.Value)             // Collect values only
        .ToList()                         // Convert to list
        .FindIndex(p => Regex.IsMatch(p, patternToMatch))
```

Comment: Good linq solution.

Comment: It is straight forward and deals with the task in two steps: 1) gets all the words 2) finds the first one that matches the pattern. That is how I understood the question. It is also concise.

Comment: You can wrap this into an extension method as in OmegaMan's answer if you wish.